# Link from one overlay to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

I use JQuery Tools for its overlay feature.

My issue here is, I want to have a link in one overlay to open another overlay while closing the existing overlay.

How can I make it work?

```
<a href="#" class="takeatour" rel="#sitetour1">Site tour</a>

<div class="overlay" id="sitetour1">
Step 1 <a href="#" rel="#sitetour2">Click here to learn more</a>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="sitetour2">
Step 2
</div>


        $("a[rel]").each(function(i) { 
            $(this).overlay({ 

                // common configuration for each overlay 
                oneInstance: false,  
                closeOnClick: true,     
                expose: '#3FB8AF',
            });             
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
$('a[rel=#sitetour2]').click(function(e) {
    $('a[rel=#sitetour1]').overlay().close();
});
```

​

Comment: Also I think this is an important feature Jquery tools overlay is missing. I want to be able to fix it with an automated way

Comment: @Efe I've updated the answer.. It works.. Here is jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/KdGfW/  You could ofcourse add some classes or data attributes to make it a little cleaner.

Comment: this is very strange because it does not work when I put it on the website, try it here; http://www.insead4sq.com click on explore button. The whole thing gets messy when the learn more link is clicked in the first overlay...

Comment: The issue with your site is the z-index of the overlay. Make sure and set its class to something higher than that of the feed to the right.